# Add 'a href' row to key value table with hyperlink using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink, html-table

The table below creates a key value (all text) table for column name and associated property.  How can I create a special case to ensure a hyperlink for the value from column 'url' instead of text like the rest.

With the following..

```
var table = $("<table><tr><th>Column</th><th>Value</th></tr></table>");
var keys = Object.keys(properties);
var banProperties = ['geom'];
**var url = ['url'];**
for (var k = 0; k < keys.length; k++) {
  if (banProperties.indexOf(keys[k]) === -1) {
    var row = $("<tr></tr>");
    row.append($("<td></td>").text(keys[k]));
    row.append($("<td></td>").text(properties[keys[k]]));

    //Add conditional statment here to ensure href instead of text
    //    on column 'url'

    table.append(row);
  }
}
```

I get this...
[image]

I have tried something like this...

```
var table = $("<table><tr><th>Column</th><th>Value</th></tr></table>");
var keys = Object.keys(properties);
var banProperties = ['geom'];
var url = ['url'];
for (var k = 0; k < keys.length; k++) {
  if (banProperties.indexOf(keys[k]) === -1) {
    var row = $("<tr></tr>");
    row.append($("<td></td>").text(keys[k]));
    //row.append($("<td></td>").text(properties[keys[k]]));
    row.append($("<td></td>").html('<a href="#">Foo</a>'));
    table.append(row);
  }
}
```

Which produces the following result...

[image]

How do I combine these methods to only create hyperlink on 'url' field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if current column is the url:

```
var row = $("<tr></tr>");
row.append($("<td></td>").text(keys[k]));
if (keys[k]=='url'){    
    row.append($("<td></td>").html('<a href="'+properties[keys[k]]+'">'+properties[keys[k]]+'</a>'));
}
else{
    row.append($("<td></td>").text(properties[keys[k]]));
}
table.append(row);
```

Comment: your response directly  answers my question. And I got it working as desired with the slightest adjustment. sp. -  if ((keys[k]) == 'url') {...    Thank you for the quick response!

Comment: You are very welcome. I'm glad I could help you ! Yes, sorry for the text(), it was a mistake. I edited it now.

Answer (score 1):

The following code would automatically render any Value as a URL, if it is detected as such (UNC only for now, but you can extend the RegExp).

```
function ValidURL(str) {
  var pattern = new RegExp('^(\\\\[^/\\\]\[":;|<>+=,?* _]+\\[^/\\\]\[":;|<>+=,?*]+)((?:\\[^\\/:*?"<>|]+)*\\?)$','i');
  if(!pattern.test(str)) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}

var table = $("<table><tr><th>Column</th><th>Value</th></tr></table>");
var keys = Object.keys(properties);
var banProperties = ['geom'];

for (var k = 0; k < keys.length; k++) {
  if (banProperties.indexOf(keys[k]) === -1) {
    var row = $("<tr></tr>");
    row.append($("<td></td>").text(keys[k]));

    if (ValidURL(properties[keys[k]]) {
      row.append($("<td></td>").html('<a href="' + properties[keys[k]] + '">click here</a>'));
    } else {
      row.append($("<td></td>").text(properties[keys[k]]));
    }

    table.append(row);
  }
}
```